# Codeblocks runtime error with graphics.h based program

Tags: c++, bgi

I tried running the program from this link in Codeblocks-
https://www.planet-source-code.com/vb/scripts/ShowCode.asp?txtCodeId=7939&lngWId=3

The program runs but prematurely stops with an error-
'drawing operation was attempted when there was no current window'.

Can anyone suggest a fix for this or any alternative headers for graphics-based operations in C?

(N.B.:I'm using the default GNU GCC compiler)

Comment: Nobody's going to download random code from the internet and debug it for you. Why are you so certain that the problem is related to a *header*?

Comment: Please make a small example of the problem : [link](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
 char driver[] = "";
 initgraph(&gdriver, &gmode, driver);
```

at the start of your program.